# Flask: Request works on browser but not on Postman

Tags: flask, postman, flask-restful

I'm creating a simple Flask app. My problem is that when I try to do a request from Postman, I alway get a `501 Not Implemented`.
However, if I do the request directly from my browser, I got a successful response.

My code is:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Logs(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(Logs, '/logs')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, load_dotenv=True)
```

I'm not sure what is causing Postman to not being able to communicate with the app.

I'm sure I'm sending a `GET` request from Postman.
I'm attaching my Postman request configuration as an image.
[image: Postman Request]

Comment: Make sure you are sending `GET` request from the postman and Also URL is correct.

Comment: I'm sure I'm sending a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you put your request type to **GET** and not to **POST** on Postman? The error usually means that the server doesn't know the request type and maybe expects a **POST** request but a post request **hasn't been implemented** in the Resource in your flask endpoint.